# Riemann-Roch Theorem for projective normal curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective integral curve over algebraically closed $k$ and let $f: Y \to X$ be the normalization of $X$.  Let $p \in X$ a closed point $q \in Y$ be a closed point contained in the preimage or fiber $f^{-1}(p)$ of $p$. Denote by $D_q= [q]$ the associated Weil divisor (a $0$-cycle of $Y$) to $q$.

I have to show that there exist some other $0$-cycle $Z$ which is disjoint from the fiber: $Z \cap f^{-1}(p)= \emptyset$ of $p$ rational equivalent to $[q]$: recall rational equivalent ( $[q]\sim Z$) means that $[q]=Z +[div(s)]$ for some rational function $s$ on $Y$.

In the hint is adviced to use Riemann-Roch (for curves). I have no idea how to exploit RR here. RR gives

$$\dim _{k}H^{0}(Y,{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y}(D))-\dim _{k}H^{0}(Y,\omega_Y \otimes {\mathcal  {O}}_{X}(-D))=\operatorname{deg}(D)+1-g_Y$$

for arbitrary divisor $D$ on $Y$, dualizing sheaf $\omega_Y$ und genus $g_Y=\dim_k H^1(Y,\mathcal  {O}_Y)$.

Now I'm looking for a $0$-cycle $Z$ with property $D:= Z - [q]$ and $H^{0}(Y,{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y}(D)) \neq 0$ contains a section $s$ with $[div(s)]=D$. I not understand why RR provides the existence of this $s$. Could somebody help me to understand how this RR hint has be to applied here? beside RR, how the normality of $Y$ comes into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riemann Roch tells you that for divisors of sufficiently large degree, the global sections of $O_Y(D)$ have dimension $\deg(D)-g_Y+1$, and this lets you build sections with desired zero sets. In your case, consider a large positive divisor $D$ of support disjoint from your point $P$, and consider the sections of $O_Y(D)$ and $O_Y(D+P)$, viewing these as subsheaves of the fraction field $K(Y)$. As subsheaves of $K(Y)$ these are given by $$L(D)(U)=\{f\in K(X)|\text{div}(f)+D|_U\geq 0\}$$

By our sufficiently large hypothesis, there exists a global section of $L(D+P)$ that doesnt arise from $L(D)$, which after translating through the definitions gives a function $f$ in $K(X)$ which has an order $1$ pole at $P$, and all other poles contained in the support $D$, and zero set also disjoint from $P$. So by construction we have the divisor $Z=P+\text{div}(f)$ disjoint from $P$.

The normality here is critical, in that we needed our curve to be nonsingular to use Riemann Roch, and normal=nonsingular in dimension $1$, so by normalising, we resolved the singularities of $X$.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer. One little remark: we required that $Z$ is not only disjoint from $q$, but the whole fiber $f^{-1}(p)$. But I think that is not a problem: $f^{-1}(p)$ is finite and I see no problem to start with a large positive divisor $D$ that avoids a finite number of points.

Comment: Oh yep, sorry about that, you're right. We just need to do this process for our finite set of points to get our function with poles of the right degrees at each point in $f^{-1}(p)$.